# Moment Generating Function Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

[image]

I'm very stuck on this question, I'm not sure where I'm supposed to start. Any help would really help

Comment: Odd question.  The usual way is a change of variables in the pdf.

Comment: check characteristic function at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Proof_of_classical_CLT   see Proof of classical CLT

Answer (score 0):

- Look up the MGF for the $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $N(0,1)$ distributions.
- The MGF of $Z$ is $M_Z(t) = E[e^{tZ}]$ by definition. Plugging in the definition of $Z$ yields $E[e^{t(X-\mu)/\sigma}] = E[e^{(t/\sigma) X}] e^{-\mu t/\sigma} = M_X(t/\sigma) e^{-\mu/t}$. Plug in the formula for $M_X$ and check that the end result is the MGF of the $N(0,1)$ distribution.

Comment: So I found the moment generating function for the normal distribution which is e^(t^2/2) but I'm not sure what to do next